# Get UILabel font pointsize after minimumFontSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a UILabel with a font of point size 17. If I call label.font.pointSize I get 17, which is all good. BBUUUUTTT I also have a minimumfontsize set to 8, now if I cram some text in the label which causes the point size to shrink and then call label.font.pointsize I still get 17 even though I know the point size is smaller

Any ideas how to get the true point size after system has resized the font?

Comment: Not directly but you can calculate it.  See the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669844/how-to-get-uilabel-uitextview-auto-adjusted-font-size

Comment: It's annoying because `UILabel` does have the information in a private property called `_scaledMetrics` which is an instance of `_UILabelScaledMetrics`. That class has a `_actualScaleFactor` property. But all academic as it's not publicly available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As savner pointed out in the comments, this is a duplication question. The cleanest solution is found here: [How to get UILabel (UITextView) auto adjusted font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669844/how-to-get-uilabel-uitextview-auto-adjusted-font-size). However, Sanjit's solution also works! Thanks Everybody!

```
CGFloat actualFontSize;
[label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
         minFontSize:label.minimumFontSize
      actualFontSize:&actualFontSize
            forWidth:label.bounds.size.width
       lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
```

Comment: Can anyone translate this solution into Swift?

Comment: @Narwhal My solution for Swift is to create a subclass or category in Objective-C and use it in Swift. Not recommended, because the method is deprecated, but there is no alternative way to get the actual font size.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of an API to get the current point size of the UILabel when it is scaling your content down. You can try to approximate "scaling factor" using `sizeWithFont` APIs.

Just an idea:

```
// Get the size of the text with no scaling (one line)
CGSize sizeOneLine = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];

// Get the size of the text enforcing the scaling based on label width
CGSize sizeOneLineConstrained = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:label.frame.size];

// Approximate scaling factor
CGFloat approxScaleFactor = sizeOneLineConstrained.width / sizeOneLine.width;

// Approximate new point size
CGFloat approxScaledPointSize = approxScaleFactor * label.font.pointSize;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4** and **iOS 7+** version (`sizeWithFont` is now deprecated) of @Sanjit Saluja's answer:

```
// Get the size of the text with no scaling (one line)
let sizeOneLine: CGSize = label.text!.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: label.font])

// Get the size of the text enforcing the scaling based on label width
let sizeOneLineConstrained: CGSize = label.text!.boundingRect(with: label.frame.size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: label.font], context: nil).size

// Approximate scaling factor
let approxScaleFactor: CGFloat = sizeOneLineConstrained.width / sizeOneLine.width

// Approximate new point size
let approxScaledPointSize: CGFloat = approxScaleFactor * label.font.pointSize
```