# Check UILabel scale in code? (set via autoshrink and minimumScaleFactor)

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

UILabel has a property 'Autoshrink' in the Attributes Inspector, where a Minimum Font Scale can be selected, the equivalent in code being UILabel's [minimumScaleFactor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/minimumScaleFactor) property.

Is there a way in code to determine the following?

1. *if* a label has been scaled
2. *what* it has been scaled to

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/131139

Comment: I'm trying to ensure that two UILabels are the same font size. I've attempted other solutions listed in StackOverflow without luck(eg. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20829315/3220708) and seem to me to be a little OTT. The simplest solution seems to me to read the UILabel scale in code(and it would also be surprising to me if this is not possible), so this is where I'm starting.