# Match font size of two UILabels

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, size

Is there a way to match the font size for two UILabels in a view that both use the minimum font size to fit in the view? Right now one label is made with much smaller text and the other is bigger. I want them to average their font sizes to fill the screen, but also look similar in size.

Comment: Here's the same question in Objective-C. Should at least give you an idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262156/autolayout-link-two-uilabels-to-have-the-same-font-size

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks - I will give that a try